# Simple 2D Curl example with units?

Tags: kinematics, units, dimensional-analysis, vector-fields, flow

I'm studying Calculus, not physics, but was curious how units work when we consider curl over a 2D velocity field. Given $\mathbf{F} = M(x,y)\mathbf{i} + N(x,y)\mathbf{j}$ the curl is defined to be $(\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y})$.

Since F is a velocity field I'd expect $M$ and $N$ to have a unit like m/s. Then since the partial derivatives are accelerations (derivatives of velocities) I'd expect them to have a unit like m/s^2, except the velocity is varying with position, not time, so is the unit m/m? Making it unitless? Even if it had a different unit in the denominator, I don't see how to get back to something like m/s or radians/s? Which I assume is what I should get since curl is described as the "rate of rotation" at a point.

Relevant Khan academy: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/curl-grant-videos/v/2d-curl-formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have demonstrated with the formula for curl, taking the curl of a vector field involves dividing by units of position. This means that the curl of a velocity field (m/s) will have units of angular frequency, or angular velocity (radians/s). The reason we can replace m/m with radians is because the radian is fundamentally a ratio of distances (namely, the ratio of arc length to radius). Thus, it's consistent to think of the curl as the rate of rotation (i.e. angular velocity) of a test particle placed very close to the point at which the curl is measured.

Comment: But if I swap in radians for m/m the unit of my result is still radians, not radians per second. How do I get a denominator from taking the difference of two radians?

Comment: Your field originally had units of m/s, right? Then the curl will have units of (m/m)/s, or radians/s.

Comment: The field was m/s yes, and we said the accelerations were m/m or equivalently radians. This makes the curl formula the difference of two radians... but I think my mistake is that acceleration is not m/m but (m/s)/m. Then if m/m is radians you get radians/s.

Comment: The derivatives in the formula for curl are _not_ accelerations. They are derivatives with respect to position, not time.

Comment: I was misusing the terminology, acceleration just meaning any derivative of velocity.

Comment: But that's not what acceleration means, so you shouldn't expect these derivatives to have the same units as acceleration.

Comment: Yes that's why I said misuse, I was just clarifying my intent.